# When the player dies it is subtracting 2 hearts instead of 1 heart. What can I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player dies it is subtracting 2 hearts instead of 1 heart. The player has 5 hearts, I put a debug log and it shows "4 3" when he dies once, then "2 1" an so on. Here are my scripts:
This if for Lives Manager

```
void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

void Start()
{
    livesTxt.text = "Lives - " + playerLives.ToString();
}

public void Lives()
{
    playerLives -= 1;
    Debug.Log(playerLives);
    livesTxt.text = "Lives - " + playerLives.ToString();
}
```

And here it runs the script

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Water")
    {
        
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY), Random.Range(minZ, maxZ));
        player.transform.position = randomPosition;
        LivesScore.instance.Lives();
    }
}
```

How can I substract only 1 heart?

Comment: Seems your `Lives` method is called twice. Maybe the `OnTriggerEnter` is fired multiple times?

Comment: I'm also with derpirscher, maybe add a boolean between that code to ensure it triggers only once?

Comment: A simple way to debug this is to add a `Debug.Log` or a break-point where `Lives` is called, then see the stack trace or function call history. You'll know exactly why the function is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the **OnTriggerEnter()** method is called twice.
I think [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/738991/ontriggerenter-being-called-multiple-times-in-succ.html) might be a solution.

In a nutshell:
If you are using a sphere or capsule collider it may touch the trigger collider with two points simultaneously. This can be fixed by using a boolean check.

(Taken directly from the linked post)

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider hitObject)
{
    if(isColliding) return;
    isColliding = true;
    // Rest of the code
}

void Update(){
    isColliding = false;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.